# Which Optimization Technique does CARET use when Training a Model, say glmnet?

Tags: r, caret, glmnet

I am trying to understand the mechanics behind the training of models. Specifically, I need to know how R's CARET package trains models.

Which technique or algorithm is applied? Usually for linear classification models, such as glmnet (logistic regression with regularization), a gradient descent algorithm is used but I connot find any documentation of the proess on the [CARET guide](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`caret` is a wrapper package that unifies the call of a (large) bunch of algorithms and makes common tasks like cross-validation easy. As such it is not performing any optimization itself.

For a given penalization (lambda, alpha), the solution of logistic regression in `glmnet` basically is found by iteratively performing a quadratic approximation to the likelihood and solving it by coordinate descend.